# Grabbing mysql query with JDBC and sending to elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash, kibana

Good Moring,
I'm trying to grab data from MySQL database and send it to elasticsearch, so I could create graph's in Kibana and display it.

I'm using the elasticsearch-jdbc plugin with this config:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/home/USERNAME/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_NAME"
    jdbc_user => "USER"
    jdbc_password => "PASSWORD"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT * from eps"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
       hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
       sniffing => false
       index => "eps"
       document_type => "eps"
       document_id => "%{uid}"
       }
}
```

And without success.
When I'm looking at the /var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log
I get this error:

```
[2016-11-17T11:54:17,592][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] fetched an invalid config {:config=>"input {\n  beats {\n    port => 5044\n   y\n }\n}\n\noutput {\n  elasticsearch {\n    hosts => [\"localhost:9200\"]\n    manage_template => false\n    index => \"%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}\"\n    document_type => \"%{[@metadata][type]}\"\n  }\n}\n\ninput {\n  jdbc {\n    jdbc_driver_library => \"/home/USERNAME/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40/mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar\"\n    jdbc_driver_class => \"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver\"\n    jdbc_connection_string => \"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_NAME\"\n    jdbc_user => \"USER\"\n    jdbc_password => \"PASSWORD\"\n    schedule => \"* * * * *\"\n    statement => \"SELECT * from eps\"\n  }\n}\n\noutput {\n  elasticsearch {\n       hosts => [\"localhost:9200\"]\n       sniffing => false\n       index => \"eps\"\n       document_type => \"eps\"\n       document_id => \"%{uid}\"\n       }\n}\n\n", :reason=>"Expected one of #, => at line 5, column 2 (byte 42) after input {\n  beats {\n    port => 5044\n   y\n "}
```

I have created new id name using:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{
>     "type" : "jdbc",
>     "jdbc" : {
>         "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MY_DB",
>         "user" : "USER",
>         "password" : "PASSWORD",
>         "sql" : "select * from eps"
>     }
> }'
```

I have changed for this post the USERNAME and PASSWORD, but I made sure - and they work. it's not that.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks
Idan

Answer (score 1):

The error message says your configuration is invalid.

From the error message, we have this:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    y
  }
}
```

The `y` has nothing to do here and the problem is coming from it. It was also at the end of the error message.

Comment: Agreed, it doesn't seem that logstash takes the same configuration file as the one that is in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that. when I'm trying to fetch information from the server I get this error:  
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason" : "no such index",
        "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
        "resource.id" : "jdbc",
        "index_uuid" : "_na_",
        "index" : "jdbc"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
    "reason" : "no such index",
    "resource.type" : "index_or_alias",
    "resource.id" : "jdbc",
    "index_uuid" : "_na_",
    "index" : "jdbc"
  },
  "status" :

Comment: When I fetch for river: curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/river/_search?pretty&q=*'
{
  "took" : 54,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
 But when trying to view in Kibana, there is noting

Comment: @Idan-Red I don't know why you get such result. And for Kibana, you might not see existing documents, depending on how the index_pattern is configured, which timestamp is on the document and which interval is used in visualisation

Comment: @baudsp thanks for all the help. I see in the log file that it's correct now: [2016-11-17T13:24:00,018][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] (0.001000s) SELECT * from eps
Where else can I check for information and data?

Comment: You can check with the _search endpoint on your index (eps), which will allow you to check if you have any data in that index. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-count.html can also be used. Other than that, you'll need to say what kind of information you want